# how to register plain js function to @Output in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling

I have a function in the `script` tag in **index.html** `hideAppLoader()` and there is an angular app component in index.html. I want to call that function when the application got bootstrapped. I have tried with `@Output` but this is not working. Here is the code

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <script>
     function hideAppLoader() { debugger;}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-app (onAppLoad)="hideAppLoader($event)"></my-app>
</body>
```

and in the **ts** file

```
@Output() onAppLoad = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
  this.onAppLoad.emit();
}
```

but the function is not getting called even there is no error on the console. I have even tried `(onAppLoad)="this.hideAppLoader($event)"` and `(onAppLoad)="window.hideAppLoader($event)"`

What is the solution or is even possible to call plain js function from angular component when it is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Since the script function is global you do not need to use and EventEmitter. just change your `ngOnInit` to be:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  window.hideAppLoader();
}
```

Judging by the name of `hideAppLoader` you could define the loader inside of the `my-app` tag and Angular will remove it once the AppComponent is Loaded.

```
<my-app>
  <img src="assets/loader" />
</my-app>
```

Comment: it is showing `hideAppLoader` is not function of window but when I try on console it exists in window object

Comment: This is because TypeScript does not think it is part of the `Window` interface. Either cast the `window` object to an `any` and call the function or add the function to the interface: `declare global {
  interface Window {
    hideAppLoader: () => any;
  }
}`